# ImportError raised when trying to load 'projects.templatetags.markdown_extras': No module named 'markdown'

Tags: python, django, django-templates, markdown, importerror

InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'projects.templatetags.markdown_extras': No module named 'markdown'

I am getting the above error.

i have django - 4.1 version and python 3.10.5

i have installed the markdown. but getting error in line- import markdown in the templatetags/markdown_extras.py.

not sure what's the problem. can anybody please help?
thank you in advance

Comment: use pip3 to install markdown

Comment: tried that, didn't work. getting requirement already satisfied

Comment: if your project inside virtual env then install it there only